# What happens to an app when its development certificate expires?

Tags: ios, certificate

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/), in-house apps will stop working once the Distribution Certificate expires:

> **iOS Distribution Certificate (in-house, internal use apps)**
>
> Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with
>   this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that
>   is signed with a new certificate.

My question is:

Is it the same for apps built with an iOS **Development** Certificate? My guess is yes, but I would like to know for sure...

*Please note: I'm not asking what will happen to apps in the App Store, I know they are not affected.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.